# How can I plot graphic b[a[x]] after having defined a[x]?

Tags: plotting, function-construction

I'm very new to Mathematica and I need it to create a (simple) theoretical model.

I'm struggling to plot graphic `b[a[x]]` after having defined `a[x]`, so far my code is:

```
a[x_] := Exp[x]; 
b[x_] := (a[x]/(a[x] + 1))^(1 - 3/10);
Plot[b[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

What am I missing? Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Did you try to restart Mathematica?

Comment: I just did, Thank you very much! It is working

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it seems to be [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD), i.e it arises from a simple mistake (Needed a fresh Kernel) and is unlikely to help any future visitors, or else it is easily found in the documentation. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
a[x_] := Exp[x];
b[x_] := (a[x]/(a[x] + 1))^(1 - 3/10);

Plot[b[a[x]], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope that helps.

**Edit**

I took your first line literally. As @roman465 suggests do you just want `b[x]` ?

If so

```
Plot[b[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is this what you need? Can't see why it did not work for you although comments now suggest that restarting worked.  Before defining a function then `ClearAll` is useful to remove previous definitions. I would have done

```
ClearAll[a, b];
a[x_] := Exp[x];
b[x_] := (a[x]/(a[x] + 1))^(1 - 3/10);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working still.. And I copied your code. I don't understand if it's a fault in my programme.

Comment: @Hugh notice that `b[x]` (what OP is actually asking) and `b[a[x]]` are different functions.

Comment: @roman465 I added an edit. Thanks for noting the alternative interpretation.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. If my code was correct it must've been that the variables where defined somewhere else or that the programme had too many pages opened. Thank you for your help !

Comment: @MarV Happy to help. The standard approach for you now is wait for a day or so and if you don't get a better answer then accept mine and the case is then nicely closed. You also might like to see how to post code etc. Welcome to Mathematica stack exchange.